# What tasks can't be accomplished without full control administrator privilege?

Tags: windows-7

Can you name tasks that can't be accomplished without full control administrator privilege?

For instance, deleting Guest account or deleting system processes. I'm trying to map all features that need special permissions from an administrator.

Comment: For what purpose? This smells like homework to me.

Comment: You can delete the Guest account on Windows.  Your list is going to be dozens of pages long.

Comment: Installing services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listing everything one by one would be very long, as Ramhound pointed out. But to broadly answer the question, a regular user cannot run any program (including built-in Windows programs or commands) that attempt to do the following:

- Modify, create or delete any folder (and/or files therein) where they do not have permissions to access (by default the Windows system folder and subfolders, Program Files, other User folders, etc)
- Modify the system registry outside of their own hive (this would subsequently disallow access to changing system settings or user accounts)
- Installing, modifying or deleting services

They also cannot run an executable that requests administrator permission, even if it doesn't necessarily ask to do these things right off the bat.

Related: [Why use a standard user account instead of an administrator account?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/why-use-a-standard-user-account-instead-of-an-administrator-account), [What is a standard user account?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-a-standard-user-account)

> When you use a standard account, you can use most programs that are installed on the computer, but you can't install or uninstall software and hardware, delete files that are required for the computer to work, or change settings on the computer that affect other users. If you're using a standard account, some programs might require you to provide an administrator password before you can perform certain tasks.